# How to change CSS with jQuery change and this

Tags: jquery, css, this, onchange

I am trying to change the text color of a selected radio button. The following code should work but for some reason it does not.

CSS:

```
.opts {float: left; padding-left: 5px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="opts"><label><input class="ws" type="radio" name="ptype" value="1">A</label></div>
<div class="opts"><label><input class="ws" type="radio" name="ptype" value="2">B</label></div>
<div class="opts"><label><input class="ws" type="radio" name="ptype" value="3">C</label></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ws').change(function(){
    var c = this.checked ? '#ff0000' : '#0099ff';
    this.css('color', c);
  });
});
```

I can replace the "this.css" with $('.opts') but then, of course, all text changes color. My problem is not being able to make the "this" work. Any help?

Comment: Change `this` to `$(this)`

Comment: tried, but did not work, I should have mentioned it...

Comment: Jquery methods can't be applied on DOM element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the color of closest `.opts` like following.

```js
$('.ws').change(function() {
    $('.opts').css('color', '#0099ff'); 
    $(this).closest('.opts').css('color', '#ff0000');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="opts"><label><input class="ws" type="radio" name="ptype" value="1">A</label></div>
<div class="opts"><label><input class="ws" type="radio" name="ptype" value="2">B</label></div>
<div class="opts"><label><input class="ws" type="radio" name="ptype" value="3">C</label></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a jquery object. Which is `$(this)` and you need to traverse up with closest method:

```
 $(this).closest('.opts').css('color', c);
```

Comment: The problem with your answer is that it turns the text red next to the clicked radio button but it does not toggle it back to blue when I click another radio button. @Azim above has a working solution.

Comment: Absolutely. As that was answered and I am on handheld device, typing is a bit slower.